# opencascade migrating from AIS_DimensionOwner to PrsDim_DimensionOwner

Tags: opencascade

AIS_DimensionOwner class is deprecated and PrsDim_DimensionOwner is the new one. Iam migrating old code from 6.5.0 to 7.6.0.

before I had:

```
Handle(AIS_DimensionOwner ) own1 = new AIS_DimensionOwner (this ,7);
own1->SetShape(mySShape);
```

and now:

```
Handle(PrsDim_DimensionOwner) own1 = new PrsDim_DimensionOwner(this, PrsDim_DimensionSelectionMode::PrsDim_DimensionSelectionMode_All ,7);
```

but the second line above, I didn't find an equivalent

I would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention from which OCCT version you are porting legacy code to which new one.

According to git log, `AIS_DimensionOwner::SetShape()` has been removed in OCCT 6.7.0 in '2013 by [0024133: Development of improvement of dimensions implementation; new length, radius,diameter and angle dimensions](https://git.dev.opencascade.org/gitweb/?p=occt.git;a=commitdiff;h=a6eb515f9d6430bce09c4dcc0f088bcfea6bb6c6#patch43).

I cannot find direct description, but it looks Shape property has been removed as irrelevant and unused. So that the main thing to pass is appropriate enumeration value to class constructor and second line could be just removed, if no further application code reads Shape back. Otherwise, you may make a subclass and add this property on your own.

Comment: sorry, I updated my question with the version number. I will try your recommendation.